# Change color in choices elements

Tags: surveyjs

How can I change the colors of each element of a choice, try this way but it remains the same.

[image]

I tried to place the styles linearly but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with SurveyJS, but this might be helpful https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/survey-customcss/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render choices using [Markdown](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/edit-survey-questions-markdown/reactjs) and apply required styles at this point. Please refer to the following demo for more details: [Markdown Radiogroup (Showdown)](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/survey-markdown-radiogroup/reactjs).